NPM Run fails with unexpected server response
i need help o solve the problem:
error: FATAL Failed to initialize the connection: Unexpected server response 502.
received this error after i have executed:
npm run MYAPP --verbose transfer -- --to ENDPOINT
Any informations to this error?
npm run ENDPOINT causes this error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
